# Generic constraint on constructor of generic class

Tags: c#, generics

I have a container class which has to instanciate a `Form` at some point. 90% of the time, the form will have a parameterless constructor. Therefore it's convenient to constrain the generic parameter to `new()` so you can instanciate it directly.
However, I'd also like to be able to pass in a factory method which creates the form for me in case it requires some parameters. This last point of course means that I can't constrain the generic type to `new()`.

```
class Container<TChild>
    where TChild : Form, new() // <-- this new() constraint should go away (Form would stay)
{
    private readonly Func<TChild> _createChild;

    public Container()
        // where TChild : Form, new() <-- this is what I want instead of the class-wide new()-constraint but that doesn't compile
    {
        _createChild = () => new TChild();
    }

    public Container(Func<TChild> createChild)
    {
        _createChild = createChild;
    }

    public void ShowChild()
    {
        _createChild().Show(); // you could substitute the Form-contraint with whatever you like and act accordingly here
    }
}
```

Without using a second class (which I'd like to avoid), my only idea was to use a static helper function for the `new()` case.

```
public static Container<TParamlessChild> Create<TParamlessChild>()
    where TParamlessChild : Form, new()
{
    return new Container<TParamlessChild>(() => new TParamlessChild());
}
```

However, I have multiple issues with this:

1. In my use case, 90% of the time I would use this since almost all of the children I'd use have a parameterless constructor. Since the generic type in my static helper function can only be more constraint than the generic type of the class, I can't turn it around either. I'm not a fan of providing a helper function to instanciate a simple object of a type but not one for a more complex object of a type, that's exactly what a parameterless constructor is for.
2. I have to specify a completely useless and unrelated generic parameter in order to even get access to the static function. `Container<SomeForm>.Create<OtherForm>();` but `SomeForm` doesn't have any impact. I'd have to create a non-generic (& static) class just for this helper method to get around this.
   If I have to use a helper function, I'd want to be able to call `Container<MyForm>.Create();` and get an object of type `Container<MyForm>` but that doesn't work because I can't constrain the generic parameter for a non-generic method even if it's inside a generic class (see the following snippet which doesn't compile).

```
public static Container<TChild> Create()
    where TChild : Form, new()
{
    return new Container<TChild>(() => TChild());
}
```

Is there any way to work around this other than what I've already mentioned? If not, could I improve my work-around?
As you can see by the comments in the first snippet, semantically, I want to be able to have a constructor which is generically more constraint than the class itself.

Comment: The "have a non-generic static class for the generic method" approach is the usual and common approach for this. There's no tax on classes and there's little to no impact on discoverability (since the class has the same name). Alternatively, don't use `new()` and check for the presence of a parameterless constructor at runtime with reflection. (I know, we all love static typing, reflection is slow and icky, etc., but in practice this is rarely a big problem.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert Luckily this is not a real real world scenario otherwise I'd have gone for the non-generic class or done it inline immediately (probably shouldn't waste company hours on something like this). I'm currently learning rust which infers generics almost everywhere so I thought maybe c# has a way to make that last snippet (or something along those lines) work since you can't constrain the constructor. Thank you for the answer :)

Comment: Rust's generics (like C++'s templates) are purely a compile-time feature. Whereas .NETs generics also have runtime aspects (that is, they exist in their generic form in the compiler output and can be consumed by calling code that hasn't been written yet using as-yet-unknown types). This leads to different outcomes in what can and cannot be done.

Comment: C#'s generics (or rather .NET's) are not like Rust's, or C++ templates, or any of the other stuff the really cool kids use; they're more limited, pragmatic beasts. People often get bitten by the fact that generic constraints don't participate in overload resolution, for example. And no, you can't constrain type parameters except at the point where they are first declared.

Comment: Thank you both, I guess I shouldn't expect that much from .net generics (or at least not those exact things, .net generics are still quite mighty). Do you want to add an answer or can/should I leave the question as is?